# Binary data however oversampler states it is multilabeled

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, imbalanced-data

I am using the Kaggle's Twitter Dataset and I am trying to oversample the minority class.

Despite y being binary, the oversampler returns an error stating that it is multi-class

[image]

My x and y are the tweets and the labels respectively.

Comment: Please don't post images of code/errors.  See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more tips.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I had to do reshape(-1,1) instead or (1,-1)